# Find the smallest and largest distance between two points distributed in 3D space

Tags: computational-geometry, distance, nearest

Suppose I have some 3D points, e.g. `{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1.3}, {0, 1, 0}, {1.2, 0, 0}}`. Now I want to find the smallest and largest distance between two points.

A trivial way is to find all possible distances, then look for the smallest and largest number.This becomes very much time-consuming for large data sets.

Could you please suggest any alternative?

Comment: The _smallest_ distance can be found with `Nearest`. For small point sets `DistanceMatrix` computes all distances in one go.

Comment: The complexity of finding the _largest_ distance can be reduced with `ConvexHullMesh` since the maximal distance must be realized by points on the boundary of the convex hull. Depending on the distribution of points, this may have a tremendous effect (or not).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, Thanks for writing, but if I use Nearest[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1.3}, {0, 1, 0}, {1.2, 0, 0}}], then it gives  "NearestFunction[{4,3},<>]
".     Unable to get that, Please help

Comment: I am a bit occupied at the moment. Please read the "Details and Options" section in the documentation of `Nearest`. (It is _always_ a good idea to **read the documentation** of a new built-in symbol first.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, OK thanks

Comment: Also the max distance I believe is the diameter of the minimal enclosing sphere. There are various exact and approximate methods for this that do better than n^2 complexity.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I can't figure out what you meant when you said that the smallest distance can be found with `Nearest`. I can't think of a way to find the pair of points closest together using `Nearest`, short of trying all pairs, which is probably not better than `DistanceMatrix`. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Nope. Think of an equilateral triangle: The circumradius is larger than the edge lengths of the triangle, but the latter are the maximal distances.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the simple counterexample. I should have thought of that.

Comment: This is probably relevent: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.157.9213&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Henrik meant the following approach using [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest):

```
min[pts_] := Min @ Nearest[pts->"Distance", pts, 2][[All, 2]]
```

Let's compare the above approach with a simple version based on [`DistanceMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix):

```
min2[pts_] := With[{dm = DistanceMatrix[pts]},
    Min[dm + Max[dm] IdentityMatrix[Length[pts], SparseArray]]
]
```

Sample data:

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[10,{1000,2}];
```

Timing comparison:

```
min[pts] //RepeatedTiming
min2[pts] //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.000693, 0.009433}
>
> {0.00629, 0.009433}

A similar treatment is possible for the maximum distance, but is much slower:

```
max[pts_] := Max @ Nearest[pts->"Distance", pts, All][[All, -1]]
max2[pts_] := Max @ DistanceMatrix[pts]
```

Comparison:

```
max[pts] //RepeatedTiming
max2[pts] //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.019, 13.7336}
>
> {0.00296, 13.7336}

Note that methods to compute the maximum distance based on [`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh) will be slower than using [`DistanceMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix), e.g.:

```
ConvexHullMesh[pts]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.012535, Null}

which is already 4 times slower, without computing any distances yet. Also, methods computing a bounding ball will not yield the correct result. For example, consider an equilateral triangle in 2 dimensions:

```
With[{eq = SSSTriangle[1, 1, 1]},
    Graphics[{eq, Circumsphere @@ eq}]
]
```

> [image]

Clearly the diameter of the circle is larger than the maximum distance.

Comment: Thanks Carl, this is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out all the distances by calculating the `DistanceMatrix`. Using `Min` and `Max` you can find the smallest and largest values.

```
dm = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1.3}, {0, 1, 0}, {1.2, 0, 0}} // DistanceMatrix
closest = Min@dm (* is 0 since the point is infinitly close to itself. *)
furthest = Max@dm 
closest2 = # /. 0. -> Infinity & /@ dm // Min
```

Comment: From the OP: "A trivial way is to find all possible distances, then look for the smallest and largest number." which is what you suggested. I think the OP wanted something faster that could work for large point clouds.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks, didn't read that.

Comment: Well, for the max distance you don't have to; you can rely on algorithms that calculate the convex hull and then measure that; alternatively, as Daniel Lichtblau suggested in comments, you can calculate the minimal enclosing sphere (which happens to also be implemented in the `BoundingRegion` function. The point of the OP was to see if there is an algorithm to **avoid** the calculation of all distances.