# NearestTo causes a kernel crash when applied to a list of SparseArrays

Tags: bugs, sparse-arrays, nearest

Nearest and [NearestTo](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestTo.html) cause a kernel crash on Mathematica 12.0.0 for Mac OS X. (running on OS X 10.11.6) when operating on a list of [SparseArray](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) vectors.

Here's my minimal breaking example:

```
examples = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}
sparseExamples = SparseArray /@ examples

NearestTo[First@examples]@examples (*works OK*)

NearestTo[First@sparseExamples]@sparseExamples (*causes a kernel crash*)
```

This appears to be confined to Nearest and [NearestTo](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestTo.html); other functions such as [DistanceMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix.html) work fine on SparseArrays.

```
DistanceMatrix[sparseExamples] (*works OK*)
```

This appears to be a "new" problem; there are a couple posts from ~18 months ago that imply that Nearest plays well with SparseArrays:

- [How to find k largest element and their position in a matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178320/how-to-find-k-largest-element-and-their-position-in-a-matrix/178321#178321)
- [Find the smallest and largest distance between two points distributed in 3D space](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192636/find-the-smallest-and-largest-distance-between-two-points-distributed-in-3d-spac/192801#192801)

It's also a bit surprising, given how many different data types Nearest and NearestTo operate on.

Comment: Interesting bug report!  Unfortunately, it is not appropriate for stackexchange which is a Q&A site, so you get -1 from me.  I recommend editing your post to turn it into a question (like asking for a workaround or something like that).  Also, I recommend submitting the bug report directly to Wolfram Research.

Comment: Confirmed. I'll report it as a bug.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question.

Comment: Confirmed crash for 12.0 on Win 10 Ent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment thread, is a confirmed bug Mathematica 12.0 on both Mac OS X and Windows.

Interestingly, for `NearestTo[x][elems]` this is only a problem if *both* `x` *and* `elems` are SparseArrays.

Converting at least one of these to [Normal](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) form avoids crashing.  So for the previous example data:

```
examples = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}
sparseExamples = SparseArray /@ examples
```

either:

```
NearestTo[Normal@First@sparseExamples]@sparseExamples
```

or

```
NearestTo[First@sparseExamples]@Normal[sparseExamples]
```

will yield the desired answer without crashing the kernel.  The former is probably closest to the desired behavior, as it keeps the list of elements in SparseArray format (saving memory), and returns a SparseArray result.